# Will oxalic acid react with ethanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, alcohols, esters

Will oxalic acid, in a saturated solution in ethanol, be able to undergo an esterification reaction with the ethanol? This is assuming no acidifying agents (or anything else, for that matter) are added, and room temperature is also assumed.

I tried to find an equilibrium constant to predict the extent of such a reaction, but I couldn't seem to find anything. This suggests either that the reaction does not take place, or that it is so obscure that nobody has bothered to examine it.

Comment: I heard that someone put a lot of effort in finding kinetics of such reaction, but in case of acetic acid. Oxalic is stronger so reaction should be faster, but still not very fast.

Comment: [Here](https://www.scribd.com/document/255144891/Eco-friendly-Esterification-of-Oxalic-Acid-With-Ethanol-Using-Mesoporous-MgAlPO4-Catalyst) is an article where they developed a catalyst for the esterification, suggesting it's probably not very fast without a catalysts...for whatever that's worth ;)

Comment: it does in presences of dehydrating agent (an agent help in pull water molecule) such as conc. sulphouric acid